# Android: hide top status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

Can I hide the Android top status bar (time & charging icon appears)?
Actually there is some difference in the positing of elements when i run things on device and on emulator. I want to run my code and many different emulators for testing purpose, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dynamically in Java**

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

OR

Declare in menifest.xml like..

```
Add the following in application if you want to remove it for all the activities in an app:

<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">

Or for a particular activity:

<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

EDIT:-

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

And write following in oncreate() method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: I am asking about the system bar and i have edited the question, on which charging icon and time appears.

Answer (score 4):

To completely remove system bar from Android Emulator(tested with Android 4.0.3):

- Navigate to %USER_HOME%\.android\avd\avd_name.avd\
- Edit config.ini :

  hw.mainKeys=no  - turn system bar OFF
  hw.mainKeys=yes - turn system bar ON

Comment: Thank you, this is the right answer. Config files are way more reliable than UI :P

Answer (score 1):

try something like this :

```
         <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
           </activity>
```

Or do something like this before your setContentView() in onCreate

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
```

Comment: I am asking about the system bar and i have edited the question, on which charging icon and time appears.